# Extracting various URL parameters in Rest Service and then passing it to Builder class

Tags: java, url, rest

I have a service which takes a lot of key value parameters in a URL. Only a few are mandatory and others are optional. It's up to the customer whether they want to set those optional parameters or not.

The mandatory parameters are `userid` or `flowid`. They can be set together or independent of each other so below are the possible combinations:

- http://localhost:8080/base/v1/lookup?userid=12345
- http://localhost:8080/base/v1/lookup?flowid=abcdefgh
- http://localhost:8080/base/v1/lookup?userid=12345&flowid=abcdefgh

Now if the full URL is to be made along with other optional parameters, then the URL will look like this:

> ```
> http://localhost:8080/base/v1/lookup?userid=12345&flowid=abcdefgh&timeout=200&dataflag=false&processflag=true&linkvtou=true&linkutou=false&maxid=3&startdate=12345&enddate=54321&holdertype=id1&holdertype=id2&attr=@kite&count=1&hide=5
> ```

Here are the parameters my URL will take and the same parameters I am setting it in my `RequestKey` builder class. My `RequestKey` builder class has default values for some optional fields like all boolean variables, `maxid` field, and timeout.

- `UserId`: This will always be a `String` (can be number as well).
- `FlowId`: This should always be a `String`.
- `Timeout`: This should be a `long`. By default this is 200 ms.
- `DataFlag`: This should be a `boolean`. By default this value is true if they are not passing.
- `ProcessFlag`: This should be a `boolean`. By default this value is true if they are not passing.
- `LinkVToU`: This should be a `boolean`. By default this value is true if they are not passing.
- `LinkUToU`: This should be a `boolean`. By default this value is false if they are not passing.
- `MaxId`: This will be a `long`. By default this is 5.
- `StartDate`: This will be a `long`.
- `EndDate`: This will be a `long`.
- `HolderType`: This is a `List` of `String`, `List<String>`.

---

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;

private final DataClient dataClient = DataFactory.getInstance();
private static final int PETA_ID = 100;

public Response lookup(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    Optional<String> client = TestUtils.getClientId();
    if (!client.isPresent()) {
        // logging here
        return Response
                .status(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED)
                .entity(Collections.singletonList(new DataResponse(null, new ResponseError(
                        HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "client id is null or empty",
                        "FAILURE")))).build();
    }

    Map<String, String> inputParameters = TestUtils.convertMultiValueMapToRegularMap(uriInfo.getQueryParameters());
    if (MapUtils.isEmpty(inputParameters)) {
        // logging here
        return Response
                .status(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity(Collections.singletonList(new DataResponse(null, new ResponseError(
                        HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Input Keys are null",
                        "FAILURE")))).build();
    }

    String userId = inputParameters.remove("userid");
    String flowid = inputParameters.remove("flowid");
    String timeout = inputParameters.remove("timeout");
    String dataflag = inputParameters.remove("dataflag");
    String processflag = inputParameters.remove("processflag");
    String linkvtou = inputParameters.remove("linkvtou");
    String linkutou = inputParameters.remove("linkutou");
    Long startdate = Longs.tryParse(inputParameters.remove("startdate"));
    Long enddate = Longs.tryParse(inputParameters.remove("enddate"));
    Integer maxid = Ints.tryParse(inputParameters.remove("maxid"));
    String holdertype = inputParameters.remove("holdertype");
    List<String> linkHoldertype = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!TestUtils.isEmpty(holdertype)) {
        linkHoldertype = Arrays.asList(holdertype.split(","));
    }

    org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders reqHeader = new org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders();
    reqHeader.add("client_id", client.get());

    RequestKey requestKey = null;
    try {
        Builder builder = new RequestKey.Builder(PETA_ID)
                .addHeaders(new HttpEntity<Object>(reqHeader))
                .addTimeout((long) (Longs.tryParse(timeout) == null ? 200 : timeout))
                .dataFlag(TestUtils.isEmpty(dataflag) ? true : Boolean.parseBoolean(dataflag))
                .processFlag(TestUtils.isEmpty(processflag) ? true : Boolean.parseBoolean(processflag))
                .linkUToU(
                        TestUtils.isEmpty(linkutou) ? false : Boolean
                                .parseBoolean(linkutou))
                .linkVToU(
                        TestUtils.isEmpty(linkvtou) ? true : Boolean
                                .parseBoolean(linkvtou));

        if (!TestUtils.isEmpty(userid)) {
            builder.setUserId(userid);
        }
        if (!TestUtils.isEmpty(flowid)) {
            builder.setFlowId(flowid);
        }
        if (!TestUtils.isEmpty(startdate)) {
            builder.startDate(startdate);
        }
        if (!TestUtils.isEmpty(enddate)) {
            builder.endDate(enddate);
        }
        if (!TestUtils.isEmpty(maxid)) {
            builder.maxId(maxid);
        }
        if (!TestUtils.isEmpty(linkHolderType)) {
            builder.addHolderType(linkHolderType);
        }
        // now only attributes will be left in the map
        if (!TestUtils.isEmpty(inputParameters)) {
            builder.paramMap(inputParameters);
        }
        requestKey = builder.build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // logging here
        return Response
                .status(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity(Collections.singletonList(new DataResponse(null, new ResponseError(
                        HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, ex.getMessage(), "FAILURE"))))
                .build();
    }

    List<HolderResponse> beResponse = dataClient.getUserDataSync(requestKey);

    boolean successFlag = false;
    List<DataResponse> responseList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (HolderResponse response : beResponse) {
        int errorCode = response.getError().getCode();
        if (errorCode == HttpServletResponse.SC_OK) {
            successFlag = true;
        }
        ResponseError error = new ResponseError(errorCode, response.getError().getStatus(), response.getStatus()
                .name());
        ResponseData data = new ResponseData(response.getResponse(), response.isLink(),
                                            response.getType(), response.getCreationTime(),
                                            response.getDay(), response.getInfo());
        DataResponse cosResponse = new DataResponse(data, successFlag ? null : error);
        responseList.add(cosResponse);
    }

    return Response.status(successFlag ? HttpServletResponse.SC_OK : HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .entity(responseList).build();
}
```

`convertMultiValueMapToRegularMap` method:

```
public static Map<String, String> convertMultiValueMapToRegularMap(MultivaluedMap<String, String> input) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (input == null) {
        return map;
    }
    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : input.entrySet()) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append(',');
            }
            sb.append(s);
        }
        map.put(entry.getKey(), sb.toString());
    }
    return map;
}
```

The `RequestKey` builder takes all these input parameters which has default values for all `boolean` variables and for all non `boolean` variables. If you try to set with empty, null values, it throws `Exception`, so that's why I am doing an empty, `null` check before setting it.

Also, if any response is successful with my array, it gives a 200 HTTP status code. If all the responses have an error, then it returns a 500 HTTP status code.

I'd like any improvements here. I am on Java 7 as of now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some comments that I had when reading through your code:

- Avoid calling [`inputParameters.remove(key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) just to retrieve the value for the given key. Not all maps support the `remove` operation, so you might end up with an [`UnsupportedOperationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html). What you really want is to `get` the value for a key, so just call `inputParameters.get(key)`.
- I'd refactor the code mapping the `Map<String, String> inputParameters` into `RequestKey` object into a dedicated method: it would avoid having the code manipulating and the code transforming the request in the same place. This is generally a good practice: make your methods small, concise and to the point.
- The builder logic is awkward:

  ```
  if (!TestUtils.isEmpty(userid)) {
      builder.setUserId(userid);
  }
  ```

  surrounded by the try-catch mixes 3 differents concepts: validation, defaults and building. The code-smell here is the long try-catch: try-catch blocks should be as minimal as possible, catching the most specific exceptions. The longer they are getting, the more chance there is that things are not decoupled enough.

  - You should first validate all your input parameters: are the boolean (resp. number) values really booleans (resp. numbers)? Are the required parameters present? If one the parameter is incorrect then you can safely return a `SC_BAD_REQUEST`. I noticed in your current that you are in fact not validating that one of `userid` or `flowid` was present. We could then imagine a method containing that logic:

    ```
    private boolean validateInputParameters(Map<String, String> inputParameters) {
        // return true or false whether the parameters are correct or not

        // validate that either userid or flowid are set
        String userid = inputParameters.get("userid");
        String flowid = inputParameters.get("flowid");
        if (isEmpty(userId) && isEmpty(flowid)) {
            return false;
        }

        //validate that dataflag is a boolean
        String dataflag = inputParameters.get("dataflag");
        if (!"true".equals(dataflag) && !"false".equals(dataflag)) {
            return false;
        }

        // rest of validation ...

        return true; // everything was correct
    }
    ```

    Note that this could use other helper methods like `isNumber` that would determine if a `String` can be parsed into a number. The advantage is that if your requirements change in the future (for example, the timeout must be less than a certain number), you only need to change this method. Even for boolean parameters, there is an advantage: in the future, you might want to add support for `"t"` or `"f"`.
  - Decoupling defaults with the building process is more trickier and context-dependent: is the builder supposed to know where the value it's using are coming from? Should it know the default values? At the very least, we can create helper methods like `private boolean getBooleanParameterOr(String key, boolean defaultValue)` that would convert a raw `String` into a `boolean` with a default value if the value is empty. Then, we can imagine a method:

    ```
    private RequestKey convertToRequestKey(Map<String, String> inputParameters) {
        boolean dataflag = getBooleanParameterOr(inputParameters.get("dataflag"), true);
        // the same for the rest of the parameters
        // ...
        builder.dataFlag(dataflag);
        // ...
        return builder.build();
    }
    ```
- Finally, the last part of the code is also converting a `beResponse` into a `responseList`. This could also be refactored into a dedicated method:

  ```
  private List<DataResponse> convertToResponseList(List<HolderResponse> beResponse) {
      // do transformation here
  }
  ```

With all those comments, you could have the following main method:

```
public Response lookup(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    Optional<String> client = TestUtils.getClientId();
    if (!client.isPresent()) {
        // return SC_UNAUTHORIZED here
    }
    Map<String, String> inputParameters = TestUtils.convertMultiValueMapToRegularMap(uriInfo.getQueryParameters());
    boolean valid = validateInputParameters(inputParameters);
    if (!valid) {
        // return SC_BAD_REQUEST here
    }
    RequestKey requestKey = convertToRequestKey(inputParameters);
    List<HolderResponse> beResponse = dataClient.getUserDataSync(requestKey);
    List<DataResponse> responseList = convertToResponseList(beResponse);
    // return SC_OK or SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR response here
}
```

which I feel is clearer and separates each part of the code.